# Disable tapping on group header in LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have a simple LongListSelector from wp7 toolkit. Now I want to disable opening popup when anybody taps on the group header. How to reach that ?

Comment: Isn't the popup kind of the whole point of the LongListSelector? (I assume you mean the popup which shows which letters of the alphabet you have content for).

Comment: it may be an alphabet or name of the month in my case. I simply want to disable this popup. While I haven't "clean" solution, I use CloseGroupView() on GroupViewOpened event of LongListSelector

Comment: @Paul Annets -- I think this is a reasonable question. Say you want to hide the popup when there is only item in the popup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't specify the `<GroupItemTemplate>` element in your `LongListSelector` and this will disable the fullscreen jump list.

Answer (score 0):

A LongListSelector shows fullscreen. Why would a popup ever happen? If for some reason stuff is being done behind the screens have a boolean set to true everytime the user taps on the longlistselector and only show the popup if that boolean is false

Comment: I can't understand your post :(. "Why would a popup ever happen?" - It's a default behaviour. I want LongListSelector ignore any taps on the group headers.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here about looking like a popup and being a System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup  ;)